# Getting all articles related to a query without a bias

Tags: python, google-api, nlp

I trying to build a corpus of documents related to earthquakes. I want to download all news articles related to that event. My problem is that using google search(stackoverflow.com/questions/…) gives bias with respect what is revelant now. Instead I want all articles irrespective of time or relevance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Google is trying to guess what is the **most relevant** search result for a user entering your query, and you are interested in all of them.

You would be better served by a newspaper article database than by Google in this case. If you are currently enrolled in a university, ask your library for this kind of resource. If you have access to such a database, you will be able to search for every article containing a given keyword, and some search forms will even let you filter by publisher, by date, by geographical location, etc...

[Eureka.cc](http://www.eureka.cc/default.aspx) is an example of such a database.

Some newspapers' websites will give you access to their article archive. [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com) is one of those.

[Here is a result searching in their article database for "earthquake".](http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/?action=click&contentCollection&region=TopBar&WT.nav=searchWidget&module=SearchSubmit&pgtype=Homepage#/earthquake)

[More info about newspaper article databases](http://www.smccd.edu/accounts/csmlibrary/tutorials/newspaper.htm)